# How do I convert an array of seconds to time series array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, time

I have an array like this (in seconds)
`timebin= [79203 79213 79223 79233 79243 79253 79263..................82783]`
and I wish to convert these values to actual time of the day like `[22:00:03, 22:00:13,.........22:59:43]`
I have the following code but it doesn't convert an entire array to time array in one go and only takes single values of `timebin`.

```
timebin1=np.arange(79203,82793,10)
print(timebin)
import time
t= time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(79203))
print(t)
```

output for now is only the first value of the required time series, i.e, 22:00:03

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to apply that function to each element in the list.

```
convert_time = lambda t: time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(t))

times = [convert_time(t) for t in timebin1]
```

For slightly faster results and a more convenient API, you can vectorize the operation:

```
import numpy as np

vectorized_convert_time = np.vectorize(convert_time)
times = vectorized_convert_time(timebin1)
```